# Making gnome-screensaver auto-lock in XFCE

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, lock-screen, gnome-screensaver

`gnome-screensaver` has been vastly simplified for major version 3 and no longer supplies the preferences dialog. It is now only useful for locking the screen and providing an unlock dialog.

I use **12.04 LTS** at the moment and am able to install `gnome-screensaver` version **3.4.1-0ubuntu1** and add it to the XFCE session's application autostart list. `gnome-screensaver` then works when I select Lock Screen from the panel.

I am, however, unable to configure `gnome-screensaver` to auto-lock the screen. There is no obvious configuration file or dialog where I can set the timeout.

Right now I use `xscreensaver` to achieve auto-locking but I don't really care about screensavers, I prefer auto-lock and display suspend via DPMS. Right now `xscreensaver` doesn't really play well with `lightdm` on my system - user switching requires the password to be entered twice:

- user a lock-screen: press New Login
- lightdm: enter user b password
- user b xscreensaver lock-screen: enter password again

I should mention that this system was installed as Ubuntu years ago and I've been installing various `xubuntu-desktop` meta-packages to try out various desktop environments.

Can anyone help me set up `gnome-screensaver` auto-lock?

Comment: Is there an "outdated" tag for questions? light-locker takes care of this use-case in Xubuntu (except for on those systems where it's buggy, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604 ), while gnome-screensaver 1) also requires  entering password twice, and 2) can't auto-lock on XFCE without also running gnome-session, see  https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5927

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a configuration front-end to gnome-screensaver that does not exist, use the `xfce4-power-manager` via the `xfce4-power-manager-settings` to lock the screen. 
Specify a timeout to your liking.

If this does not work for you, install the package `dconf-tools`, run `dconf-editor` and edit the items under `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` to your liking.